# Position of Centre of Mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Prove that:

$$\vec{R}_{CM}  =\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n M_i\times \vec{R}_i}{\sum_{i=0}^n M_i }$$
Where, $\vec{R}_i$ and $M_i$ are the position vector and the mass of $i^{th}$ particle in the system respectively.

I am not able to understand from where to start. so please help.

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of Centre of Mass,  the entire mass of the system is assumed to acts at the centre of mass.

Consider a frame in which the position vector of $i^{th}$ particle is $R_i$ and its mass is $M_i$. Total mass of the system is 
$$M=\sum_i M_i$$
Let $R_{cm}$ be the location of the centre of mass measured in this frame. Then the placing the body in a gravitational field, the moment about the origin of the frame due to the $i^{th}$ particle is

$$m_i = M_ig\times R_i$$
The net moment due to all the particles is 
$$m=\sum_i M_ig\times R_i$$

When the entire mass is assumed to act at the centre of mass, the net moment about the origin is
$$m=Mg\times R_{cm}$$

Comparing the above two relations for total moment $m$, we get the expression of centre of mass position vector as
$$R_{cm}=\frac{\sum_i M_i\times R_i}{\sum M_i}$$